# Can't initialize a NULL char array?

Tags: arrays, c, null, char

I have to inizialize a char array [DIM_MAX] to a null value in order to pass it to another function. Before passing it to this function, I am trying to print it as a local variable in order to understand if it assumes a value of zero, but unfortunately this does not happen.

I did:

```
 static char bufferW[DIM_WRITE];
```

Then I wanted to inizialize this buffer to zero. Is correct to do this?

```
*bufferW="NULL";
```

I have to pass it to the function

```
write(0x02900800, bufferW, DIM_WRITE);
```

but bufferW isn't passed as a NULL char, it is the last value assumed. Where am I doing wrong? I tried:

```
bufferW==NULL;
```

is the way? I am sorry for the basic question.
Any help will be appreciated

kind regards

Comment: As an object with `static` storage class and no initializer - it is already initialized to all zeros. But from your attempts it looks like you might not be having the basics to do the things you are trying to do...

Comment: Are you trying to set your string to "NULL" or the string pointer to NULL?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up null pointers, the numerical value null (zero) and the string literal `"NULL"` – looks pretty much as if you are in urgent need of a [good C book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)...

Comment: I am so sorry, but I cannot use strcpy...how can I initialize a string to null? If I write NULL in the write function it works

Comment: that string is initialized to null already because you declared it static

Comment: also note that `==` is the comparison operator, `=` is the assignment operator. But neither makes sense in this context for `bufferW=NULL` or `bufferW==NULL`. `bufferW` is a static array, not a pointer. It exists in the same place in memory for the duration of the program. Your insistence that `bufferW` is NULL (in whatever sense) is also unclear. Most assuredly the `write` function is expecting a pointer to a block of data of a specified length (`DIM_WRITE` in your case). Passing it a NULL pointer will at best cause nothing to happen, and at worse invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: if you want `bufferW` to be initialized with the string `"NULL"`, then you can simply do `static char bufferW[DIM_WRITE] = "NULL";`, assuming that `DIM_WRITE >= 5`, but based on the other parts of your question, probably not what you want.

Comment: Ok thanks to all, I am Sorry but i am not a programmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bufferW` is an array, which takes up `DIM_WRITE` bytes.

If you're trying to set every byte in the array to 0, the function you want to call is

```
memset(bufferW, 0, DIM_WRITE); //Make sure to #include <string.h>
```

If you don't have access to the functions prototyped in `string.h`, you can also overwrite the buffer with a simple loop such as

```
for(int i = 0; i < DIM_WRITE; ++i)
  bufferW[i] = 0;
```

You can do this at any time in your program to overwrite the values in `bufferW`, but if you haven't written anything to the buffer yet, the `static` scope specifier in the declaration ensures it will be initialized to zero at the start of your program.

To write the string "NULL" in the buffer you can

```
strcpy(bufferW,"NULL"); //Make sure to #include <string.h>
```

Or manually write each character in the buffer

```
bufferW[0] = 'N';
bufferW[1] = 'U';
bufferW[2] = 'L';
bufferW[3] = 'L';
bufferW[4] = '\0'; //Null terminator
```

But for these to work DIM_WRITE must be at least 5.